# Confusion related to matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-distribution

I am having this simple confusion.Lets consider a multivariate gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and precision matrix $K$. Then the exponential term is

$$(x-\mu)' K (x-\mu)$$

If I open the above expression, I will get
$x'Kx- x'K\mu-\mu'Kx + \mu'K\mu$. The middle two terms are not equal, they were supposed to be same.

So I am wondering if I am doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The two "middle terms" are each other's transposes.  Generally a matrix is not equal to its transpose.  But notice that these are $1\times 1$ matrices, and every one of those is equal to its transpose.

Comment: Perhaps you may want to comment on the complex Gaussian case.

Comment: @Soth: In the complex Gaussian case, I would take $A'$ to mean the conjugate-transpose of $A$.  The matrix $K$ in the middle would be its own conjugate transpose (it may be defined as $\mathbb E (X-\mu)(X-\mu)'$, where $\mu=\mathbb E X$.)  So $(x'K\mu)'=\mu'K'x=\mu'Kx$, and again, the two middle terms are equal.

Comment: (If I'm not mistaken, $A'=\text{conjugate-transpose of }A$ is consistent with the usages of matlab and mathematica and the like.)

Comment: A slight mishap; they become each other's conjugates (they are not equal), and their sum becomes real (as we expect). I just wanted to comment on that case as, as you said, the notation $(\cdot)'$ is sometimes taken for Hermitian transpose.

Comment: You're right: their conjugates of each other.